# Gulp build results in webpack error with terser: Unexpected token: punc (:)

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, gulp, terser

Here's the error log for reference:

```
[00:13:30] [Webpack errors]:
[00:13:30] activity-sidebar.js from Terser
Unexpected token: punc (:) [webpack://./node_modules/box-ui-elements/node_modules/setimmediate/setImmediate.js:80,12][activity-sidebar.js:30380,18]
    at js_error (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:550:11)
    at croak (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1274:9)
    at token_error (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1282:9)
    at unexpected (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1288:9)
    at semicolon (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1326:56)
    at simple_statement (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1583:73)
    at statement (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1369:47)
    at _embed_tokens_wrapper (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1339:26)
    at block_ (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:2172:20)
    at statement (/Users/bustosman/Documents/GitHub/Box/Integration/node_modules/terser/dist/bundle.min.js:1403:29)[00:13:30]
```

I started having issues after installing Box's box-ui-elements npm package. It had a problem with peer dependencies at first (axios and ts).

This is the only webpack error I get. My github repo: https://github.com/BustosAndrew/Integration